# Puppet Disable HTTP Trace in Apache on a Single Node

Tags: apache, http, puppet

I struggle to find a way to disable the trace/track option on one of my RHEL7 servers which is controlled by puppet.

I'm using apache module of puppetlabs.

I want to disable TraceEnable in the httpd.conf file on a **single** server and not to all servers managed by puppet.

The directive I need to add using puppet is:

```
TraceEnable Off
```

I have the YAML file for the server in the location:

```
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/test/data/node/server1.yaml
```

I can edit this file to apply the config on this server only but I don't know what to put in it.

How to call the HTTP module and how to right the directive in the YAML file?

Comment: What module are you using to manage httpd?

Comment: The module is apache.

Comment: Do you mean puppetlabs-apache?  The simple name is not specific enough.

Comment: Yes it's puppetlabs. 
I'm sorry Its my first question here and I may have missed some bits. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference documentation for the puppetlabs-apache module is available [from the Puppet Forge](https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppetlabs/apache/reference).  It would tell you that the main class of that module ([`apache`](https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppetlabs/apache/reference#apache)) has a parameter [trace_enable](https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppetlabs/apache/reference#trace_enable), which controls exactly the httpd configuration property you want to manage:

> Controls how Apache handles `TRACE` requests (per RFC 2616) via the
> `TraceEnable` directive.
>
> Default value: `'On'`

Provided that your manifest set is not explicitly specifying a value for that parameter, you should be able to customize it on a per-node basis by setting the `apache::trace_enable` key in node-specific hiera data.  For example, if the node specific data for the node you want to configure is  `environments/production/data/node/server1.yaml`, then in that file, include the line

```yaml
apache::trace_enable: 'Off'
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much.